# How to get the RSSI of bluetooth device in real time in Android 4.3?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean, rssi

I am developing an application where I have to connect to Bluetooth Low Energy device on Android 4.3.

When I push the button, I can get the RSSI of the BLE device after connect to the device  by using `BluetoothLeService.readRemoteRssi();`

But I want to get the RSSI in every second ??
I have try the Runnable, but it does't call the `readRemoteRssi();` function in log.

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mBluetoothLeService.readRemoteRssi();
    mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
```

};

Where should I type the `BluetoothLeService.readRemoteRssi();` ??

in `onResume` ?? or how to do can let the APP always get the RSSI ??

Sorry for my English and I am just new to this.

Thanks for your direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solve it.

modify the code of following:

```
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {  
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mBluetoothLeService.readRemoteRssi();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
```

and add `mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);` in `onCreate`

Comment: thank you for providing your solution, since I came to this 2 years later :)